# Creating Custom Windowing Function in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a Beam pipeline that starts off with reading multiple text files where each line in a file represents a row that gets inserted into Bigtable later in the pipeline. The scenario requires confirming that the count of rows extracted from each file & count of rows later inserted into Bigtable match. For this I am planning to develop a custom Windowing strategy so that lines from a single file get assigned to a single window based on the file name as the key that will be passed to the Windowing function.

Is there any code sample for creating custom Windowing functions?

Comment: Is this a streaming pipeline? If not, you can accomplish this with a GroupByKey

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for the reply. However, based on my limited knowledge and looking at the documentation, `GroupByKey` only acts as a SQL `GROUP BY ` & doesn't  actually assign a Window. In my scenario, the lines are already grouped together based on the file name as the container i.e. the key. The issue here is to be able to insert rows (lines) belonging to the same file as part of the same window, which I believe is possible if the rows are made part of the same window just before the call to the `CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable()`.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you have already grouped the lines by file name, why do you need to insert other lines? Where are these other lines coming from?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. When I say "lines are already grouped together based on the file name", basically what I am trying to say is that I already know to which file a particular line belongs to. This is not the issue. The problem is call to the `CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable()` that needs to happen on a per window basis (1 file name = 1 window). Unfortunaltey `GroupByKey` doesn't create windows for each key. Hope his clarifies.

Comment: Hmmm in Beam windows are used to represent time, and no other dimension. If you want to window your elements, you will have to add a timestamp, and apply a windowing strategy. You could add a custom time-windowing strategy, but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I changed my strategy for confirming the inserted number of rows, for anyone who is interested in windowing elements read from a batch source e.g. `FileIO` in a batch job, here's the code for creating a custom windowing strategy:

```
public class FileWindows extends PartitioningWindowFn<Object, IntervalWindow>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -476922142925927415L;
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileWindows.class);

@Override
public IntervalWindow assignWindow(Instant timestamp) {
    Instant end = new Instant(timestamp.getMillis() + 1);
    IntervalWindow interval = new IntervalWindow(timestamp, end);
    LOG.info("FileWindows >> assignWindow(): Window assigned with Start: {}, End: {}", timestamp, end);
    return interval;
}

@Override
public boolean isCompatible(WindowFn<?, ?> other) {
    return this.equals(other);
}

@Override
public void verifyCompatibility(WindowFn<?, ?> other) throws IncompatibleWindowException {
    if (!this.isCompatible(other)) {
        throw new IncompatibleWindowException(other, String.format("Only %s objects are compatible.", FileWindows.class.getSimpleName()));
    }
  }

@Override
public Coder<IntervalWindow> windowCoder() {
    return IntervalWindow.getCoder();
}
```

}

and then it can be used in the pipeline as below:

```
p
 .apply("Assign_Timestamp_to_Each_Message", ParDo.of(new AssignTimestampFn()))
 .apply("Assign_Window_to_Each_Message", Window.<KV<String,String>>into(new FileWindows())
  .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
  .discardingFiredPanes());
```

Please keep in mind that you will need to write the `AssignTimestampFn()` so that each message carries a timestamp.